# Developer tools --> Pascal

Tags: application-development

Desde ya, gracias por dejarme participar. La pregunta es si pueden poner la opcion en Herramientas para Desarrolladores, la de Pascal. Hay muchos colegas que lo usamos. Seria bueno dejarnos compartir nuestros logros. Desde ya, saludo a la comunidad y muchas gracias. Alta Gracia - Cordoba - Argentina.

Of course, thanks for letting me participate. The question is whether they can put the option in the Developer Tools that of Pascal *(Developer Tools --> Pascal). There are many colleagues who use it. It would be nice to let us share our achievements. Of course, I greet the community and thank you very much. Alta Gracia - Cordoba - Argentina.

Comment: Pascal is a programming language, not an application. Is there some specific application (perhaps some integrated development environment for Pascal) that you want to use?

Comment: There is an IDE for free pascal called Lazarus, if you need to develop in pascal on Ubuntu. The IDE is very much like the old Delphi.

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned in the comments, [Lazarus](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lazarus/) is a Pascal IDE that is available in Ubuntu, there is also a Pascal [compiler for GCC](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gpc/).

Comment: It might be useful to point to the FreePascal compiler too, which also comes with its own terminal-based IDE ('fp-ide').